# What actually happens when the engine approaches redline and the rev-limiter is reached?

Tags: engine-theory, rev-limiter

When the rev counter approaches the red zone, the power seems to stop and nothing seems to happen after this (even if your foot is flat to the floor)

What actually happens inside the engine when the redline is approached and the rev-limiter is reached (on a stock engine)?

Comment: Sorry, really need to improve my searching before I ask

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not intended to be a great answer but just so you know the information is there...

From the [description of the rev-limiter tag](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/tags/rev-limiter/info):

> Device used in the ignition system to limit the rotations per minute (RPM) or engine speed. In newer electronically controlled powertrains, this can be done through programming of the powertrain control unit/module (PCU/PCM). The RPM is preset and will not allow the engine to go past this point. One way it can limit this by cutting the spark output to certain cylinders at certain times, which will not allow the engine to rev any higher. This helps protect the engine from accidental damage caused from stresses it was not intended to withstand.